# netbeans import library: javax.mail.*

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to import the above mentioned library [Available Here](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SingleVariationTypeFilter) in NetBeans IDE v 6.8.
I right click on my project, go to properties -> libraries and added all .jar files in the downloaded file.

Yet when I go to import the library using

```
   import javax.mail.*
```

It is not working (not showing me "mail" as an option when I type "java.".

this is 100% a dummy question but any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See if this post helps http://gpraveenkumar.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/abc-to-import-a-jar-file-in-netbeans-6-5/

Comment: thanks this was a help. this was what i did the first time but it encouraged me to retry. with this second effort, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you have to type "javax."?

Comment: I believe the original question has been modified since I entered this "answer".